# Graphics for mobile phones

Tags: color, resolution, mobile

What factors should I consider when designing and creating graphic images for smaller screen sizes?

When resizing a big image to a smaller screen size, does this increase the pixel density hence making is look more clearer?

And does this have any effects on colour depth?

Comment: You are freely mixing "smaller screen" and "higher dpi". Make up your mind: does your target screen have *less pixels* or does it have the same (roughly) amount on a smaller display?

Comment: My task is to evaluate the impact that smaller screen size (such as, mobile phones) have on the design and creation of graphic images.

Comment: @RadLexus I'm so confused how the smaller screen size affects it

Comment: Pixel density is a property of a screen, it has no bearing on graphics you still make pixels

Comment: @RadLexus A 7 inch tablet with a resolution of 1280x720 has both higher DPI and less pixels than a full HD 24 inch monitor. The two are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. None of your specific questions come to play.

The number of pixels in a digital display is fixed, so no nothing changes the pixel density of a display. Pixel density has no meaning for the generator of a image the only thing that counts is how many pixels your display has. The physical size and density are beyond your reach, but they also do not affect the end results.

Color depth is also not affected by size of a image. It is affected by the display panel again not something you can affect. Image formats do not lose or gain color depth by scaling in most cases.

Now the interpolation to a smaller scale can make the pixel image sharper due to a inbuilt sharpening algorithm. But this is still unaffected by the screen physical size, it is also sharper on a bigger screen. You could simply sharpen the image regardless, you can also upscale or downscale color depth by same token but it does not make much of a difference.

It is also hard to say anything about quality of smaller panels. Many small panels are better than average big panel screens because they are cheaper to make. On the other hand the worst quality panels out there are also small. Many budget priced small panels have a restricted color depth.

Also remember that small screens are often zoomed around so even the actual pixels on screen may not matter all that much. Maybe only thing to consider is not to make too small details.